# Boolean value not working, need a fix?

Tags: java, boolean

What I want is to output A or Z.

Everything else between A and Z works except A and Z, I tried to add an "else if"
with equals and && but it's not working.

The "System.out.println(ConvertLetterToDigit(num2));"
 takes the input and transfers it into a switch that'll give back an "int" value.

If you need more infos, please comment below ._.

```
 char num1;
 char num2;
 String num3;
 String equality;
 System.out.println("\nThis game consists of inputting a digit and we will output the character linked to that digit.");
 do 
 {
 System.out.println("Please input a letter.");
 equality= "^[a-zA-Z](1)";
 num3 = console.next();
 if (num3.length() < 2);
 {
 if (num3.matches(equality))
 {
     num2 = (char)num3.charAt(0);
    System.out.println(ConvertLetterToDigit(num2));
 }
 else if (num3.length() > 1)
 {
    System.out.println("We said 1 letter.");
 }
 else 
     {
        System.out.println("What do you think you're doing.");
    }

 }
 } while (!num3.matches(equality));
 break;
```

Comment: your if statement can never be true as you require `num2` to be 'a' and 'z' at the same time, which is obviously not possible

Comment: As a side note, have you considered [Character.isLowerCase()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLowerCase(char))

Comment: You don't need to edit the question title to indicate you've found the solution, just accepting the right answer is fine :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to check that your input is indeed a letter between `a` and `z`.

In that case, your `if` should be:

```
if( num2 >= 'a' && num2 <= 'z') {
    // okay, do something
}
else {
    // show error message
}
```

Comment: I want to 'a' and 'z' value to be included.

Comment: @MikeChouinard ...which is exactly what the `>=` and `<=` operators do.

Comment: @Mike `>=` and `<=` is inclusive, `>= 'a'` literally means "greater than **or equal to** `'a'`".

Comment: When i copied the code, the equals werent't applying, therefore my question above.

Answer (score 0):

The condition you've written is always false: you require `num2` to be equal to `'a'` AND to `'z'`. You should probably rewrite it as `num2 >= 'a' && num2 <= 'z'` (note the less/greater signs change).

Excluding 'a' and 'z' is as simple as changing `>=` to `>`, and `<=` to `<`.

`&&` means AND, `||` means OR. Use them appropriately. (A condition that matches both 'a' and 'z' would be `num2 == 'a' || num2 == 'z'`.)